# Vim-latex does not compile with \ll , but does compile with :!latex -interaction=nonstopmode %

Tags: vim, latex

Help! I followed instructions in this page http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/index.php?subject=faq&title=FAQ#faq-2

and this part **Q: Compiling does not seem to work for me. My gvim hangs/does nothing**.

Everything is fine using ":!latex -interaction=nonstopmode %", but I am unable to compile using "\ll"

The error I get is "E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &"

Note: I don't get any errors from the commands shown in the link shared. "Tex_RunLaTeX()" runs fine and all suggested solutions in that page as well.

Any ideas?

I am using Arch Linux and the latest vim-latex version 1.8.23-20130116.788.

Thank you.

Comment: put `set nocompatible` at the top of your vimrc. If you've changed your leader, use that instead of `\ll`. And to be completely clear, you are using `\ll` and not `:\ll` - right?

Comment: Thank you, mixedmath. I apologize, yes I was using ':\ll', it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

The `E10` error indicates that you've typed the plugin's `\ll` mapping in the *command-line*, whereas this is a regular *normal mode* mapping. So, return to that default mode by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>, then press (in short succession) <kbd>\</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd>. You can influence the starting key, see `:help mapleader`. Custom *Ex commands* provided by plugins always start with an uppercase letter, e.g. `:LatexCompile`.